# ios Cordova: tableview-like html

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova, web-applications

I currently focus on an iOS web app using `Apache Cordova` and `JQuery Mobile`.I want to implement a tableview-like style page (it is called `listview` in `JQuery Mobile`). I implement a initial list view in html and I'd like to: when I click the different rows, the html will send message to the iOS, and then I create a request with native code. After that, I return the successful result to js and js will update the list view which looks like you click a row in a tableview and a new page is pushed in.

The problem here is:

1. how to add the click event?
2. in the click event, how can I know which row is clicked?
3. how the tableview-like pushing animation is implemented when I use JQuery Mobile to update the list view?

I'm fresh to the web app and it costs several hours to implement dynamicly creating a list with the request result. And I totally do not know how to go further.

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I. and II. [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/fmJhF/) an example for your first and second question:

This is a code example:

```
$('ul.listview-example[data-role="listview"] li').bind('click',function(event, ui){
    alert($(this).attr('id'))
});
```

First code line will bind a click event on every listview li element. $(this) is a selected li element.

If you are using never version of jQuery us .on( instead of .bind(, in older version you can also use .live( .

**EDIT :**

III. I think this should cover your third question: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/YShLE/

Comment: ,thanks.For the third one, I'd like to update the list view content after clicking one row which looks like you click a row in a UITableView and a new page is pushed in. In other words, how to implement the push-in animation just like the UITableView does?

Comment: Take a look at the new example, I think this should cover it.

Comment: I also find that I need to read more from JQuery and implemented it. Thanks a lot!